# QGIS 3 suddenly slow

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I created a project in QGIS 2 and put in an Atlas. I then realised that QGIS 2 only allows 500 objects in the Atlas preview, which is no good to me (I've got about 2000+) so copied the project, opened it in QGIS 3 and got it working.

I was having no problems with QGIS 3 until the last step, which meant I had to create 9 extra print composers (or "layouts" in QGIS 3). These are essentially copies of the first one but with minor changes (logos, wording etc), so 10 in total.

Now, whenever I try to open the project in EITHER version of QGIS (since I also went back and created them in the QGIS 2 version in case anybody needs that), it takes forever. In QGIS 2 you can see it going through the print composers and presumably loading them into memory, and I assume the same is happening with QGIS 3 - only I thought a feature of QGIS 3 (I'm on 3.4.5) was that print composers / layouts weren't meant to be loaded on startup.

Does anybody know if there's a way to stop them loading on startup? I still need them so deleting isn't an option.

Comment: By any chance are you using html items in these layouts?

Comment: @ndawson nope, though each does have an attribute table. They are quite complex, with them showing attributes of features that intersect the Atlas. I may see if I can instead create 5 different projects, each with 2 layouts.

Comment: Hmm - could be related to the attribute tables, depending on settings. Can you upgrade to 3.4.10? There was some performance fixes for attribute tables in an earlier patch release (maybe .6 or .7)

Comment: It definitely is the amount of print layouts. I can cut it down to 2 per file (a landscape one and a portrait one). Bit of a pain but it improves load times immensely.

Comment: It's likely NOT the number of print layouts, but rather a particular item on the layouts which is causing this (i.e. 100 blank layouts = no delay, 1 layout with 100 of these items = large delay!). That's why it'd be helpful to try temporarily removing the attribute tables and see if that changes things.